# How to get the name of a directory by regex?

Tags: windows, groovy, directory, jenkins-pipeline

I need to get the path or name of a directory, the things I know about it:
- the folder the directory is on
- its name follows a given regex

How can I accomplish this?

Working on Jenkins pipeline (groovy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up assigning the result of powershell to the variable, I did this by telling the powershell step that it has a stdout return like:

```
def folder = powershell (returnStdout: true, script: """
            Get-ChildItem -directory | Select-String -pattern '<pattern>'
            """)
```

That combined with pwd() gives me the full path, although you can also get full path using a pipeline in the command, something like `Get-ChildItem -directory | Select-Object Fullname | Select-String -pattern '<pattern>'`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the [pwd](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#pwd-determine-current-directory) pipeline step to return the current directory as String and fetch the name from it by using regex groups.

See the following example to extract values from regex using groovy: https://gist.github.com/EwanDawson/2407215